# When I make an falcon API my excel is corrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, falcon

I'm trying to make a web API to save a csv into an template excel file. I have made a function which works perfect when I perform it. But once I call it from the function
(def on_get(self, req, resp): )
the file is getting corrupted. What are the changes I can make to prevent the file from getting corrupt?

Server Code:

```
class Test:
def on_get(self, req, resp):
    ct.save_df_into_excel(df_template, file_location, list_of_code_columns, new_location)
    """Handles GET requests"""
    response = {
        'status': 'success'
    }
    resp.media = response
```

function:

```
def save_df_into_excel(df_template, file_location, list_of_code_columns, new_location = None):
if new_location == None:
    new_location = file_location
if df_template.columns.nlevels > 1:
    df_template.columns = df_template.columns.droplevel()

df_new_template = df_template.reindex(columns=list_of_code_columns)
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_location, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = workbook
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)
worksheet = workbook.active
df_new_template.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=worksheet.title,
                     header=None, startrow=2, index=False)
writer.book.save(new_location)
```

Comment: For any one who would encounter this. I was not able to solve this with falcon. I removed falcon and used flask instead to make my program run again as expected.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience the best way to deal with incoming files with falcon is by using the falcon-multipart middleware, you can get it here https://github.com/yohanboniface/falcon-multipart and use it like this:

```
from falcon_multipart.middleware import MultipartMiddleware
api = falcon.API(middleware=[MultipartMiddleware()])
```

then in your endpoint use something like this:

```
class UploadHandler():
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        iFile = req.get_param('sentFile')
```